# Keyboard and Bluetooth killed when establishing FTDI USB Serial connection

Tags: macos, serial-port, arduino, tty

Okay, when I establish a connection using LabVIEW or Python to my Arduino Duemilanove (ATMega328) either my Bluetooth or keyboard is killed.

I am simply trying to establish a connection to `/dev/cu.usbserial-A9007UZh` (or `tty.usbserial-A9007UZh`, but that seems to kill the keyboard or bluetooth even after Terminal is shut down when using python).

I am on a MacbookPro, and I have found that the keyboard is on the same USB hub that one of the two USB slots is on, and the bluetooth is on the same USB hub that the other of the two USB slots is on, which explains the association between those two devices - but what is causing the loss of the other devices?

when I use Arduino (programming IDE) or Cornflake to open a serial connection there are no errors -- and everything works as expected. This just seems to happen with LabVIEW and Python.

I am on Snow Leopard 10.6.2 and have the latest FTDI USB drivers and am running in 32-bit mode.

Comment: Hi, I´m seeing the same issue - did you find a sollution to this?

Comment: So, it's been four years and three macbook pro's since the original post, and the problem has never left my side.  I feel like something is overflowing when it happens; it seems to happen more often when I have some device programmed to transmit in an infinite loop without any delay taking place in-between iterations.  The problem has occurred with every version of OS X between 10.6 and 10.10.2, and on every macbook pro (the model in this post was an early-2010 I believe, then mid-2011, currently early-2013).  It is fascinating how common yet silent the issue is.

Comment: Adding is hard.  After nearly three years of study, I've concluded that it was, in fact, five years since the original post when I left that last comment.  Not four years.

Answer (score 0):

Based on correspondence with FTDI, there seems to be a known problem with OS X drivers that can result in "complete system crash" from which "there is no way to recover". They recommend architecting software to use a dedicated thread for serial communications to ensure input data (aka, data transmitted by the device and received by OS X) is read promptly.

They mention that new "certified" (signed?) drivers should be available for OS X in Spring 2015, but don't mention if this particular problem will be solved in this new release.

Anecdotally, I have not experienced Bluetooth/keyboard crashes using OS X 10.10.2 with the built-in `AppleUSBFTDI.kext` drivers.